# Assigning multiple variables in one URL (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, php, url, url-parameters

I'm having problem passing multiple values.

setting a variable from a table in javascript funtion.

```
<td><input type="Button" value="Remove" onclick="deletefn(<?php echo $row['SKU'] ?>);"></td>
<script>
function deletefn(sku){

        location.assign('delete.php?prosku='+sku);
        }
</script>
```

But if try to put 2 variables like this it doesn,t work

```
<td><input type="Button" value="Remove" onclick="deletefn(<?php echo $row['SKU'] ?>,<?php echo $row['Part_no'] ?>);"></td>


<script>
function deletefn(sku,part){

        location.assign('delete.php?prosku='+sku);
        location.assign('delete.php?partx='+part);
        }
</script>
```

where am I doing mistake? Can someone help?

Comment: You can only call `location.assign()` once. That redirects the page to that URL, and the second call has no effect.

Comment: If you want to call `delete.php` twice, use AJAX for the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't with the function parameters, it's that only the first `location.replace()` has any effect, since it redirects and the JavaScript on this page stops running.

Assuming `delete.php` accepts multiple parameters, put them both in the same URL.

```
function deletefn(sku,part){
    location.assign(`delete.php?prosku=${sku}&partx=${part}`);
}
```